# How to select same column with different conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `table1` with these columns:

- region (varchar)
- surface (float8)
- decision (bool)

I want to select `AVG(surface)` for the cases where `decision` is `True` and where it is `False` and group the result by region.

I finally want 3 columns :

- region
- the average surface of surfaces where decision is true
- the average surface of surfaces where decision is false

I tried :

```
SELECT 
    region,
    (SELECT AVG(surface_m2) FROM table1 WHERE avis_final_bri),
    (SELECT AVG(surface_m2) FROM table1 WHERE avis_final_bri)
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY 
    region
```

but the query does not work.

I also tried to define another table the `WITH` statement but it did not work. I tried with the `JOIN` but it failed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FILTER` clause:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2f453c324cc9bef1676a60a5eb114d2d)

```
SELECT
    region,
    AVG(surface) FILTER (WHERE decision = true),
    AVG(surface) FILTER (WHERE decision = false)
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY region
```

Alternatively to use more common SQL, you can use the `CASE` clause:

```
SELECT
    region,
    AVG(CASE WHEN decision = true THEN surface END),
    AVG(CASE WHEN decision = false THEN surface END)
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY region
```